# CSS Float behavior from left to right

Tags: html, css

As far as I know, float tend to behave in this manner.

[image]

It fills the entire space from left to right as it should. My question is how to make it behave in this manner.

[image]

It would fill up the bottom part of the first column space then goes to fill the second column.

code: http://jsfiddle.net/EwqYW/

Thanks.

Comment: div which you are `floating` define is `width:100%`

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava Sorry, I added the code for easier showing of the solution.

Comment: You want it to float from top to bottom and then left to right, instead of left to right and then top to bottom?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you don't want us to simply unfloat your `div` elements. Are you looking for something like [jQuery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)?

Comment: then remove `float` it work very well...

Comment: @AndersHolmström Yes. That's the plan.

Comment: @JoshDavenport That's the one I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeroen wrote the answer. josh davenport gave the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

it's best if you move away from floating in what you want to accomplish and input:

```
display:block;
```

In place for your DOM elements.

Comment: You don't even need that for divs.

Comment: yeah i know but i just got in the habit of specifying regardless i trust no browser even for the default inherited css

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the floats!

```
.container {
    margin:0.5em;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EwqYW/11/

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
.container { clear:left; }
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EwqYW/5/.

Answer (score 1):

[Jquery Mason](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is the answer that I am looking for. Thanks Josh Davenport for pointing this out.